# The following formula is logically valid $\forall x,y,z\ (h(x,h(y,z))=y)\rightarrow \forall x,y\ (x=y)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Expanding the title I am trying to prove that $\forall x,y,z\ (h(x,h(y,z))=y)\rightarrow \forall x,y\ (x=y)$ is a logically valid formula of the first order language $L=\{h\}$, made by a single function of ariety 2.

It is clear to me that we should reason on the fact that, $h$ is a function which " extracts information" both from the first and the second of its arguments. Hence  if there are $x\neq y$ we may try to build an interpretation of $h$ so that $h(x,h(y,z))=y$ does not hold.

I have tried to play around substituting different terms (which we can obtain, I observe, only by application of $h$ to variabnles) as arguments, e..g. $h(h(x,y),h(x,y))=x$ but haven't quite reached an intuitition.

I know that there is not an algorithm to decide whether a formula is logically valid (the problem is semidecidable), but can we resort to some heuristic at least?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your heuristic is indeed correct. The proof is as artificial as the problem, but ultimately not difficult.

First, we can prove that for all $z$, the partial function $h(-, z)$ has to be injective. For if there are $y, y'$ with $h(y, z) = h(y', z)$, then $y = h(z, h(y, z)) = h(z, h(y', z)) = y'$.

But now suppose there are $x, x'$ which are distinct. Then by injectivity in the first argument of $h$, we would need that $h(x, h(x, x)) \neq h(x', h(x, x))$. But by definition, both sides of this are equal to $x$. Thus the domain contains only one element.

**Edit:** We can significantly simplify this argument as just a sequence of equalities: simply take $x, y$ in the domain, and then
$$
x = h(x, h(x, h(x, x))) = h(x, x) = h(x, h(y, h(x, x))) = y.
$$